# How to get clusters from a grid

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm looking for recommendations about a clustering problem. I'm working on a Python project where I have programmed a collective sort made by agents.

1. Overview

I have a grid of Objects placed randomly at initialization and a number of Agents which try to move objects in order to "cluster" them.

2. What I would like

I would like to evaluate the "quality" of the clustering at different times (e.g. after 1 minute of execution, after 3, after 10). So I would like to retrieve the clusters made by my agents on my grid.

3. Examples

Random initialization of the grid:

[image]

How to get clusters from this:

[image]

I'm searching for an idea to retrieve from my grid something like :

```
clusters = [
    [list of coordinates for first cluster],
    [list of coordinates for second cluster],
    ...,
    [list of coordinates for nth cluster]
]
```

I have tried some handmade algorithms but it doesn't work at all. Maybe something in scikit-learn exists but I haven't found something interesting.

Feel free to ask if my question is not clear!

Comment: So you already know which group/cluster each dot belongs to and just want to evaluate how nice the grouping is?

Comment: @Ali250 I would like to construct the clusters from my grid, so I know the color of each object and I would like to find an idea to get a list of clusters with, for each cluster, the coordinates of the points which are in it

Comment: @desertnaut where can I have a recommendation if SO is not made for that ?

Comment: Not quite sure if [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is the right place; you could always try Reddit,,,

Comment: @desertnaut I didn't know about this website, I will think about it for next time

Comment: I would kindly suggest to think about it *now*, at least if you want your question answered (it already has 2 closing votes as off-topic, and with good reason). No shame in voluntarily migrating a question, quite the contrary indeed...

Comment: Standard deviation/variance might be a good metric. For each color, compute the variance of the spatial coordinates of each dot belonging to that color. The lower this variance, the better your dots are clustered together. For an overall metric you can either take the simple mean of all the variances, or compute a weighted mean based on the number of dots belonging to each color. This method assumes that your dots follow a Gaussian distribution though, so it might not work well in cases where the dots' positions differ highly from this.

Comment: Anyway, since this is not the correct forum for this, I will refrain from continuing this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a clustering algorithm is what you want to use here, because it's the job of the agents to cluster.

But you can take some inspiration from clustering evaluation.

For example, you could compute the connected components of what your agents produced, then evaluate this using the ARI.
Or you could compute the average pair-wise distance of any two pixels of the same color, and check how this score improves over time.